# gdbserver tracepoint arm support

Tags: gdb, arm, trace, gdbserver

I compiled gdbserver 7.6 for arm with:

```
cd /gdb-7.6-src/gdb/gdbserver
./configure --target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux
make CC=/path/to/cross-compiler-gcc
```

Then I compiled gdb 7.6 for arm with:

```
cd /gdb-7.6-src/
./configure --target=arm-linux --prefix=/opt/gdb-arm/install/
make && make install
```

I compiled my trivial application with:

```
/path/to/cross-compiler-gcc hello.c -g -o hello
```

I copied gdbserver and my cross-compiled application on my board.
From my pc (x86-pc-linux) I run:

```
gdb hello
(gdb) set target-async on
(gdb) tvariable $c
(gdb) actions
>teval $c=$c+1
>end
(gdb) break main
(gdb) target remote <ipaddr>:<port>
[Thread 1585] #1 stopped.
0x40000800 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) continue &
(gdb) tstart
Target does not support this command.
(gdb) tstatus
Target does not support this command.
```

The behaviour is 'normal' until the *tstart* command: I can debug the application as I want, but I am unable to start tracing the app.

The question is: **does gdbserver support tracepoints for arm or only for x86/amd_64?**

Comment: UPDATE: it appears from the gdb mailing list that tracpoints in gdbserver are only supported for x86/amd_64.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching samething, what I've found in GDB online docs webdocs that there is no support for now to any Archs.

Check for more info:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Tracepoints.html

Quoting:

> This functionality is implemented in the remote stub; however, none of the stubs distributed with GDB support tracepoints as of this writing